# Timezone setting on local and server environment

Tags: php, laravel

Set timezone in below file. (Laravel 5.6)

config/app.php

```
'timezone' => 'America/Anguilla',
```

**Input:**

```
dd(date('Y-m-d H:i:s'));
```

**Output on local system:**

2019-10-15 04:40:16

**Output on ubuntu/apache Server (AWS Instance):**

2019-10-15 04:50:16

Why the server is ahead of 10 minutes difference.

Comment: Hi, you might want to check this, https://askubuntu.com/questions/715191/the-time-on-the-clock-is-wrong-ubuntu-14-04

Comment: Server time is wrong? :-)

Comment: in the Server terminal, while running time this command date, it returns correct time.

Comment: oh I see, I think following command sync the time .... sudo hwclock -s